# Automapping complicated nested classes and lists that need grouping

Tags: c#, .net, automapper

I am quite new with automapper and I need to map some data from 1 really complex object to another really complex obj (well atleast for me). Imagine I have a box full of toys:

```
Class SrcBox {
    List<SrcToy> SrcToys {get; set;}
}
```

every toy in the box knows its name, group name (ex. Guns) it belong to, Group order (not an order in group, but the order among groups), and the owner's name:

```
Class SrcToy  {
    string Name {get; set;}
    int GroupOrder {get; set;}
    string Group {get; set}
    string Owner {get; set}
}
```

Now I have to move all toys to another box, which has better ways of grouping toys, so now I have box with sections for every single group of toys:

```
Class DestBox {
    List<ToysGroup> ToysGroups {get; set;}
}
```

And my Groups now have their names (same names toys in SrcToys carry), their orders among groups (again from SrcToys), owner's name ( if items are in the same group they will have same owner), and a list of toys that belong to that group.

```
Class ToysGroup {
    string Name {get; set;}
    int Order {get; set;}
    string OwnersName {get; set;}
    List<DestToy> DestToys {get; set;}
}
```

And ofc DestToy class, with only name remaining:

```
Class DestToy {
    string Name {get;set;}
}
```

So now my questions are:

1. Is it even possible to map those 2 class using automapper

   `CreateMap<SrcBox, DestBox>()`... ... `Map<DestBox>(SrcBox)`
2. If yes, can some1 give me some tips, links, names I could use to solve this problem, Or even solve it for me, if its not to much time consuming. Thanks :)

Comment: Can you add `SrcBox`?

Comment: what do you mean by 'add' ? its 1st mentioned class

Comment: Oh missed it, thanks.

Comment: First understand your mapping, write it by hand, probably using LINQ. Then, if you see boilerplate code, AM can help with that. The more you have to configure AM, the less useful it is. So just use it for the simple stuff it is good at. Of course it helps to understand what AM can do :)

Comment: well I was hoping to be able to do this complex automapping by using multiple simple mappings, since I had a task and advice to do an automapper, but as far as I learned, I would still need to select most parts and build new object by hand even in automapper part of code.
I never learn, that if you cant find close answer for few days, you are probably looking for a wrong things.
Anyway. Thank you guys for tips :)